# Solve $ny(x)^2=\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}$ and determine the range of $x$ where $y(x)$ is real-valued

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, radicals

I have the following differential equation:

$$ny(x)^2=\sqrt{1+y'(x)^2}$$

I know that $n$ is a real number, and that the intial condition is $y(a)=b$, where $a$ and $b$ are also real numbers.

The questions I have are:

1. What is the function $y(x)$?
2. In what range of $x$ is the function $y(x)$ real-valued, and how does that range depend on $n$, $a$, and $b$?

Comment: @MikaelHelin it is a number, I also edited my question.

Comment: @Aryadeva How do you know the form? Is it related to mechanics? I think I remember some soap bubble problem and shortest path problem similar to this problem.

Comment: @Derik : I think my answer addresses your both questions. If not, please feel free to comment. I enjoyed this, especially the curvature ratio property defined here as a constant 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

To start with, notice that
\begin{align*}
ny^{2} = \sqrt{1+(y')^{2}} & \Longleftrightarrow y' = \pm\sqrt{n^{2}y^{4} - 1} \Longleftrightarrow \int\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\sqrt{n^{2}y^{4} - 1}} = \pm\int 1\mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}

Then WA gives the following [result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2Fsqrt%28n%5E2y%5E%284%29%20-%201%29). Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from @user1337's answer, the result can simplify as
$$x(y)=C \pm \frac{i}{\sqrt{n}} F\left(\left.\sin ^{-1}\left(y\sqrt{n} \right)\right|-1\right)$$ where appears the elliptic integral of the first kind.

Now, compute $C$ from the condition $x(b)=a$.

Answer (score 0):

Given

$$ny^{2} = \sqrt{1+(y')^{2}} \tag1$$

Instead of building variability of profiles through $n,\;$ chosen minimum radius $r_1$ instead. $ n=1/r_1^2 $ for convenience.

Using symbols $(z,r)$ in cylindrical coordinates instead of $(x,y)$. $\tan\phi=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

$$\sec\phi=\dfrac{r^2}{r_1^2} \tag2 $$

Integration gives profiles using elliptic integrals  of the first kind as mentioned by others, the numerical solution as follows.

*ODE for Shell:*

Differentiating with respect to arc length  $s$ since $ \frac{dr}{ds}=\sin \phi $

$$\frac{d\phi}{ds}=\dfrac{ 2 r \cos^2 \phi} {r_1^2 }\tag3$$

$$ r=\int \sin \phi\; ds, z=\int \cos \phi\; ds,\; BC: (s=0,r=r_1)  \tag4$$

*Second order ODE*

$$r_1^2 \phi^{''}(s)+6\sin \phi(s) \cos^2\phi(s)=0 \tag5 $$

*Profiles obtained:*

[image: Radiation Shell Profile]

Unbounded domain and range  $r> r_1$

***Curvature Relation:***

Curvature  Ratio of the two shell curvatures $(R_1,R_2)$ by definition

$$\dfrac{R_2}{R_1}= \dfrac{k_1}{k_2}=  \dfrac{\phi^{'}}{\cos \phi/r} \tag6 $$

Plug in from (2) and (3)

$$\boxed {\dfrac{R_2}{R_1} = \dfrac{k_1}{k_2}=2 }  \tag7 $$

is a very interesting geometry property of the curve. The minor shell curvature is half the major shell curvature i.e., the minor shell radius of curvature $R_2$ is double the major osculating shell radius of curvature $R_1$. This is drawn in the sketch below computed for $r_1=4$.

[image: Curvature Ratio]

The differential equation can be put in a simpler $y=f(x)$ form.

*Derivation of DE for $y=f(x)$*

The two principal shell curvatures are:

$$ k1= \phi^{'} =\dfrac {\dfrac {d^2y}{dx^2}}{(1+ (dy/dx)^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$ k2= \frac{\cos \phi}{y} =\dfrac{1}{y\sqrt{1+(dy/dx)^2 }} \tag 8 $$

Dividing and using curvature ratio formula in (7)

$$ y\cdot \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2} = 2 [1+(dy/dx)^2] \tag9 $$

which can be integrated with boundary conditions  $(x=0, y=r_1, dy/dx =0),\;$ leading exactly to the same results.